# Getting row index where a new value starts

Tags: r

I have a simple `data.frame` as created below. I want to get all the row indices where a new `origin` starts. In this case it would be 1, 5, and 8. Is there a way to do this without looping?

```
df <- data.frame(origin=c(rep('2016-01-01', 4), rep('2016-02-01',3), rep('2016-03-01',2)), 
  date=c('2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01'),
  val=rnorm(9))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$origin <- as.Date(df$origin)

df
      origin       date        val
1 2016-01-01 2016-01-01 -2.0856573
2 2016-01-01 2016-02-01 -0.5930160
3 2016-01-01 2016-03-01  0.5370460
4 2016-01-01 2016-04-01  1.5539720
5 2016-02-01 2016-02-01  0.4866211
6 2016-02-01 2016-03-01 -0.1443780
7 2016-02-01 2016-04-01 -0.9286197
8 2016-03-01 2016-03-01 -0.6311255
9 2016-03-01 2016-04-01  1.1667005
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
which(!duplicated(df$origin))
#[1] 1 5 8
```

If the values can repeat (or are not sorted), use the following to find where a series of new value begins.

```
which(c(TRUE, as.character(df$origin)[-NROW(df)] != as.character(df$origin)[-1]))
#[1] 1 5 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `rle` and `cumsum`. We `c()` a `1` onto the beginning because that's the start and then we take off the last element from the run (since there are no new elements after it). A little esoteric, but:

```
date_runs <- rle(as.character(df$origin))
cumsum(c(1,date_runs[[1]][-length(date_runs[[1]])]))
##[1] 1 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions in the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(origin) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: You'll want to create a `row = row_number()` before group_by if OP wants row numbers in the full table (rather than just taking a subset).